# How to use format function to update a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, format, sql-update

I have a column of `date` datatype (the column name is `orderdate`). I want to convert it to 'fa' culture using format function.

I wrote different kind of query such as below, but I got  different conversion error.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[orderstest] 
SET [OrderDate] = CAST(FORMAT([OrderDate], 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'fa') AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: You've just said the column is a date time data type. It therefore does not have a display format, it is stored in binary format. You format it in your front end, or as part of a select query. You don't change how it is stored.

Comment: thanks a lot so what should i do if i want to update it with 'fa' culture?

Comment: You seem to have not read or understood Dale's comment. You don't *update* a `date` data type column with any sort of formatting, dates are not stored any any particular format. The format is applicable *only* when you query the value for presentation.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[orderstest] 
SET [OrderDate] = CAST(FORMAT([OrderDate], 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'fa-ir') AS DATETIME)
```

But this is not the trust way because you are converting the original date to a Persian and then converting it to date time!
I suggest saving all dates as us-date and everywhere you want to get it, convert to Persian